# On clicking delete button , record not deleted in tosca

Tags: salesforce, tosca

I am automating a sales force application using tosca.
I have a pop up screen with delete button
On selecting delete button pop window getting closed  but the record not deleted.
I tried click ,long click , x but nothing worked.
Pls suggest a solution
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this work when you do it manually? Does Tosca {click} perform the same action that you'd perform manually? You have some timing problems with your next steps. Try adding a 'Tbox wait' after your click.